# how detect space separate words (in a full-text search query) with regex in php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I need detect words that separate with space in a text. for example my text is:

```
some parent +kid -control "human right" world
```

now I need to detect **some**, **parent**, **world**. (all words that don't have + - ( ) < > before and after, and all words inside quotes must be discarded) so I write this regex with `preg_match_all()`:

```
(?:^|[\s]+)((?:(?![\+\(\)\<\>\s\-\"]).)+)(?:[\s]+|$)
```

but it only detect **some** and **world**. how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

I need it for **Javascript** too. But it seems it doesn't work for Javascript. how can I do it with javascript?

**EDIT**

I found a solution but it seems stupid way. what is your ideas?

```
$str = 'some parent +kid -control "my human right" world';
$words=array();
$quot=false;
$discard=false;
$word='';
for($i=0;$i<=strlen($str);$i++){
    $chr=substr($str,$i,1);
    if($chr=='"'){
        if($quot){
            $quot=false;
        }else{
            $quot=true;
        }
        continue;
    }
    if($quot)continue;
    if($chr==' '||$i==strlen($str)){
        if(strlen($word)&&!$discard)$words[]=$word;
        $discard=false;
        $word='';
        continue;
    }elseif(in_array($chr,array('+','-','(',')','<','>'))){
        $discard=true;
        continue;
    }
    $word.=$chr;
}
print_r($words);//Array ( [0] => some [1] => parent [2] => world )
```

**EDIT**
Final way for PHP (this is for multi-language queries) (special thanks to rubber boots):

```
$query='some parent +kid -control "my human right" world';
$result=array();
if(preg_match_all('/(?:"[^"]+")|(?:^|[\s])(?P<q>(?:(?![\+\(\)\<\>\s\-\"]).)+)/',$query,$match)){
    $result=array_filter($match['q'],'strlen');
}
print_r($result);// some,parent,world
```

Final way for javascript (this is for multi-language queries) (special thanks to rubber boots):

```
var query='some parent +kid -control "my human right" world';
var result=Array();
var tmp;
var patt=RegExp('(?:"[^"]+")|(?:(?:^|\\s)((?:(?![\\+\\(\\)\\<\\>\\s\\-\\"]).)+))', 'g');
while(tmp = patt.exec(query)){
    if(typeof(tmp[1])!=='undefined') result.push(tmp[1]);
}
alert(result);// some,parent,world
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic. All the words are separated by spaces. Why should 'world' match but not other words? Are you saying it's OK for the space to be preceded by (but not followed by?) a `"`, but not other characters such as `-` or `+`?

Comment: `explode(' ', $search)` and you have all words, separated by a space…

Comment: @Utkanos: I need exact words that dont have prefix like + - ( ) < > and all words in quotes must be rejected. this is a search phrase

Comment: @feeela: explode will separate all words. that I need only words that don't have prefix and not quotes.

Comment: @IVIR3zaM - this is crucial information. Please edit the question and include it there, too (e.g. words in quotes should be discarded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following string is given:

```
 $t ='some parent +kid -control "human huhu right" world';
```

it's possible to extract words according to your specification with a rather simple expression too:

```
 $r = '/ (?:" [^"]+ ")? \s?
         (?<!\S) \b (\w+)
       /x';
 preg_match_all($r, $t, $matches);
```

This results in:

```
foreach($matches[1] as $m) echo $m . "\n";

some
parent
world
```

The technique used:

The expr `(?:" [^"]+ ")?` consumes the quotes and their contents.

---

Addendum: **Javascript**

For Javascript, you need to use a slightly more complicated approach, Javascript has no `lookbehind assertions`, we *fake them* with `(?:^|\\s)` in front of an allowed word.

This will work:

```
  var t = 'some parent +kid -control "human huhu right" world';
  var r = /(?:"[^"]+")?(?:^|\s)(\b\w+)/g;
  var a = [];
  while(m = r.exec(t)) a.push(m[1]);
```

We use the same technique here - generate captured submatches in `$1` for the words we need.

The contents of the array `a`, (`document.getElementById("myhtml").innerHTML = a;`)  will contain then:

```
some,parent,world
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I need it for javascript too. but it seems it doesn't work for javascript. how can I do it with javascript?

Comment: I will now go out running for a while. If not somebody else provided a Javascript solution, I'll try to. Please add a `Javascript` Tag to your question, remove your overcomplicated PHP solution and add an additional paragraph for requesting a Javascript solution instead.

Comment: @IVIR3zaM - after some discussion in another question, I simplified the expressions and removed the filter step.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$str = 'some parent +kid -control "human right" world';
$words = array_filter(explode(' ', $str), function($word) {
    return preg_match('/^[^-+"]*$/', $word);
});
echo implode(', ', $words); //some, parent, world
```

That disallows any words that contain `+`, `-` or `"`. Is that what you meant?

Note I use an anonymous function as the callback to `array_filter()`. If you're on PHP < 5.3, use a named function instead, or one made with `create_function()`.

Comment: this is nice. but have a problem. if inside quotes be more that 2 words, it detect middle words as space separated word. I need to skip all words in quotes.

Comment: Did you try the code? It returns `some`, `parent` and `world`, exactly the output you said you needed.

Comment: yes I test it. if you try this phrase **some parent +kid -control "my human right" world** it returns some, parent, human, world. that is incorrect. all words inside quotes must be skipped.

Comment: Well I couldn't have predicted this requirement from the question you posted. This requirement makes things notably more difficult, I'm afraid.